# Passing data to Laravel view based on user ID gives undefined variable error, how to fix?

Tags: laravel

Hello Please I am new to laravel I am trying to pass data to the view in laravel based on the userid of the usertype logged in. It worked for the first user but it is giving me an undefined variable error when another user logs in.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\bedDetails;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    //redirect user based on the usertype
    public function redirect()
    {
        $usertype = Auth::user()->usertype;

       
       
        if ($usertype == 'headNurseMedical') {
            $viewBedDetails = bedDetails::all()->where('userID', '=', '3');
            return view('HeadNurseMedicine.dashboard', compact('viewBedDetails'));


            
        } elseif ($usertype == 'headNurseNASurgery') {
            $viewSurgicalBedDetails = bedDetails::all(); 
            return view('HeadNurseNASurgery.dashboard', compact('viewSurgicalBedDetails'));
}else{

            return view('administrator.dashboard');
        }

This is the code that performs the redirect based on the usertype
```

```
<div class="card-body">
                          <div class="table-responsive">
                             <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>SW 1</th>
                                            <th>SW 2</th>
                                            <th>SW 3</th>
                                            <th>SW 4</th>
                                            <th>SW 5</th>
                                            <th>SW 6</th>
                                            <th>WARD G</th>
                                            <th>TROLLEYS</th>
                                            <th>PAEDIATRIC SURGERY WARD 1</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    
                                   
                                    <tbody>
                                       
                                        @foreach ($viewSurgicalBedDetails as $viewSurgicalBedDetails )
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>{{ $viewSurgicalBedDetails->fullComplement }}</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        @endforeach
                                       
                                      
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
```

The above code shows the data stored in the database table.

I checked to see if the name passed on the compact is the same as the name going to be used in the foreach loop.

Comment: What variable is undefined, it's not clear in your answer. Please include full exception message as well.

Comment: $viewSurgicalBedDetails this is the variable that is undefined

Comment: can you dd($viewSurgicalBedDetails) and check if there is data in it?

Comment: yeah I did that and there is data in the attributes array

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're facing is that when another user logs in with a different user type, the variable `$viewSurgicalBedDetails` is not defined in the controller method for that user type. Hence, you're getting an "undefined variable" error when trying to access it in the view.

Here's an updated version of your code:

```
public function redirect()
{
    $usertype = Auth::user()->usertype;

    
    $viewSurgicalBedDetails = [];

    if ($usertype == 'headNurseMedical') {
        $viewBedDetails = bedDetails::where('userID', '=', '3')->get();
        return view('HeadNurseMedicine.dashboard', compact('viewBedDetails'));
    } elseif ($usertype == 'headNurseNASurgery') {
        $viewSurgicalBedDetails = bedDetails::all();
        return view('HeadNurseNASurgery.dashboard', compact('viewSurgicalBedDetails'));
    } else {
        return view('administrator.dashboard', compact('viewSurgicalBedDetails'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue could be that you are using two of the same variable names in your `foreach` loop:

```
@foreach ($viewSurgicalBedDetails as $viewSurgicalBedDetails )
```

Change your foreach to something like this:

```
@foreach ($viewSurgicalBedDetails as $viewDetail )
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $viewDetail->fullComplement }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: thanks I have done that but the error is refering to the $viewSurgicalBedDetails as the undefined variable